# How can I create an ArrayList of Objects that has one string and 5 Integers

Tags: list, object

Is this possible? For example, say I am reading data from a file that has a name and X amount of integers. I need to add each line (every line is a different record) to the list, but they are of different types (1 string, 5 integers). How can this be done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please identify what language you are using :)

Comment: And specify the file format, as more elegant solutions could be proposed (e.g. demarshalling) if the file is in a standard format

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify what language you are using, but since you are asking about ArrayLists which are only in Java (well, they do exist in .NET, but they're more or less deprecated in favor of List, since ArrayList is untyped), I'm going to assume that's the language you're working in. Next time, please add a tag for the language you're using :-)

To answer your question specifically, you can put objects of different types in an ArrayList by declaring the type of the ArrayList to be an Object with the syntax `new ArrayList<Object>()`. Since both a String and an Integer (primitive ints get [autoboxed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_%28object-oriented_programming%29#Autoboxing) to Integer) are Objects, they can be in this ArrayList.

However, there's probably a better way to manage your data by creating a class to store your data. For instance, if you're doing inventory, you might create the following class:

```
public InventoryRecord {

    public InventoryRecord(String name, int warehouse1Count, int warehouse2Count, int warehouse3 count, int warehouse4Count, int warehouse5Count){
        //assign everything to instance variables
    }

    //Create getters and setters
}
```

Then you can just put these InventoryRecord objects into an ArrayList with `new ArrayList<InventoryRecord>()`.

Comment: Glad it helped! Please accept this answer (click the check box below the rating of this answer). We both get Reputation if you do :-)